# Finding an absolute path to a folder in Cygwin

Tags: c, eclipse, path, makefile, cygwin

I am running a Eclipse for C/C++ using cygwin GCC. I need to get the library path of "libws2_32.a", which is in   C:\cygwin\lib\w32api   for me in windows. However I do not understand how this is translated into a cygwin-path.

I've tried stuff like:

```
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/lib/w32api
/lib/w32api
/usr/lib/w32api
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: update

Here's the make Eclipse log used for building, if it helps:

```
make all 
Building target: Filesharing_core.dll
Invoking: Cygwin C Linker
gcc -L/cygdrive/c/cygwin/lib/w32api -shared -o"Filesharing_core.dll"  ./src/test.o   -llibws2_32.a
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -llibws2_32.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Filesharing_core.dll] Error 1
```

Comment: `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/lib/w32api` should work. Your cygwin must be configured in a strange way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem with the path; it's a problem with the name of the library (the `-l` option).
Where you have entered `libws2_32.a`, instead enter `ws2_32`.
See [the GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) for how the `-l` option works.

Generally, when asking for help with programming, don't describe, but show. Don't describe what you're doing; don't describe what you think the error is. Instead, show exactly what you're doing, show the exact code (or a cut down version that exhibits the same problem), and show the exact error message.
This way others don't have to guess as to what's wrong, and you are more likely to receive an answer right away that solves your problem.

Comment: I thought that was just for unix systems and not windows. It worked.

Comment: Notwithstanding, the vast majority of people who find this page will be looking for an answer to the question in the title: how to find the absolute path in Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` utility to find the file, although it may take a while.

```
find / -name libws2_32.a -print
```

**Edit:** Based on your edit to the question, simply move `-llibws2_32.a` to *before* `./src/test.o`.

Comment: I get a "File system loop detected: '/cygdrive/c/cygwin/' is part of the same file system loop as /"

Comment: Are you sure? This makefile was auto-generated by eclipse.

Comment: @KaiserJohaan, No I'm not sure but I'm guessing based on the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The folder `C:\Opt\Cygwin\lib\w32api` or whatever it is in your system is simply `/lib/w32api` from within Cygwin. The library you're looking for is `/lib/w32api/libws2_32.a`.

But I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. I guess your Eclipse in running in Windows, and not from a Cygwin'ized version of Java? Why are you using Cygwin GCC? Do you want to compile for Cygwin? If not, [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) or [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) would be the tool to pick.

If you do want to compile for the Cygwin environment using Eclipse (a combination I haven't tried), then user experience like the following might be helpful:

http://www.benjaminarai.com/benjamin_arai/index.php?display=/eclipsecygwingcc.php

(I simply googled: eclipse cygwin gcc)

Comment: No, that was just to add the gcc.exe to the PATH, not gcc lib paths unfortfunately